# PHP Simplest XML tokenizer for string processing?

Tags: php, xml, strings, parsing

I need to do some *text processing tasks* with *short XML fragments*.
The section "details" shows an example... My solution is to use a *tokenizer* based on *regular expresions*, but it is not elegant and not uses any build-in function. The candidate build-in functions (that others indicates to me) are [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) and  [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

So, my question have two parts:

1. **My assumptions are correct?** There are no other "candidates", only strtok and SimpleXML? Is correct to think DomDocument as an "elephant" (with big CPU overhead) for a simple *text processing task*?
2. **How to use SimpleXML to do the same (illustred)  task?** PS: I not need all algorithm or implementation, only some clues.

---

## Details

PHP offers a tokenizer, [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php), very simple, and I not see how to use it with XML string.
The option, [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), is perhaps heavy for tasks like ''text processing'' (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml) and the below), and is more than a tokenizer.

What exactly I whant to say with "tokenizer" and "text processing"? See example below. I used a "regex parser", but **I would like an algorithm based on some built-in function like SimpleXML, if it is simpler and faster**.

```
 $xmlFrag = '
   <p align="center">&nbsp; Hello world!</p> 
   <p class="test"><i>&nbsp; Beautiful</i> day today.</p>';
 
 // TOKENIZING TAGS AND ENTITIES:
 $reg=array();
 $xmlFrag = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<!\-\-.+?\-\->|<.+?>|&[a-z0-9]+;/is', 
    function ($m) {
        global $reg; $reg[]=$m[0]; $n=count($reg)-1;
        return "##$n#";
    },
    $xmlFrag
 );
 echo $xmlFrag;     // results:
 //  ##0###1# Hello world!##2#  ##3###4###5# Beautiful##6# day today.##7#

 // PROCESS THE TEXT: any, in one step. Example: lower, upper, change orthography, etc.
 $xmlFrag = strtoupper($xmlFrag);
 echo $xmlFrag;
 //  ##0###1# HELLO WORLD!##2#  ##3###4###5# BEAUTIFUL##6# DAY TODAY.##7#
 
 // EXPAND TOKENS:
 $xmlFrag = preg_replace_callback(
    '/##([0-9]+)#/is', 
    function ($m) { global $reg; return $reg[$m[1]]; },
    $xmlFrag
 );
 echo $xmlFrag;
 //  <p align="center">  HELLO WORLD!</p> 
 //  <p class="test"><i>  BEAUTIFUL</i> DAY TODAY.</p>
```

---

### Using SimpleXML

How to implement a SimpleXML algorithm to resolve the illustrated problem (code above)? PROBLEMS:

- Load a XML with named entities (as `&nbsp;` in the example).
- Traverse XML to get only text nodes. With `$sx->xpath('//text()');` I can not edit the nodes.

### Using DomDocument

It is out of context, because my XML fragments are short and [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) imposes a big CPU overhead (? is this a preconception?) for the simple text processing.

Comment: It's possible you have a design or conceptual programming problem here, but it's difficult to understand what you're asking.  Please [edit] your question to be more clear about what aspects you're having issues with.

Comment: I edited, but can add "PHP Simplest XML tokenizer for string processing? using regex loops or SimpleXML, or another solution?"

Comment: Why not just use SimpleXML?

Comment: I edited, see my problems when I try to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I find (!), and have a misconception about DomDocument (it is not an "elephant"):

1. DomDocument have comparable performance (times) with SimpleXML.
2. There are a simple algorithm to solve my problem!

   ```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($xmlFrag);  
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $elements = $xpath->query("//text()");
    foreach ($elements as $element) // loop for text processing:
        $element->nodeValue = strtoupper($element->nodeValue);
    print $dom->saveXML();
   ```

---

Performance (execution times for a 10000 loop):

- DOMDocument (implementation above): 0.481 seconds;
- regex tokenizer (implemention of the question): 0.571 seconds;
- SimpleXML (no implementation, only simulating iniciatizations and process): 0.481 seconds. 
  [@IMSoP shows that "traverse and edit" is more complex with SimpleXML than DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631460/287948).

Comment: SimpleXML and DOM will have nearly identical performance, since they are actually both wrappers around the same parser (libxml2), and can even be used interchangeably with `simplexml_import_dom` and `dom_import_simplexml`, which re-wrap the parsed document representation. Using manual tokenization or regular expressions rather than a dedicated parser for XML is pretty much always a bad idea, as it is a complex syntax, and there *will* be cases you don't account for.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation complements the benchmarks and our understand about it. About SimpleXML implementation of this algorithm, [you show that it is more complex than DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17618280/287948) (thanks also about it!), need recursive function, etc. So, DOM is really the better solution.